# Convert string to datetime, add one hour, and then convert it back to string

Tags: python

I have a specific string time format (I think it's ISO) that need to be added 1 hour to. So, I need to convert it to datetime first, then add 1 hour to it, and then finally convert it back to string. I'm having trouble creating the right format pattern for it. Any help is appreciated.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

# Convert string to datetime
timestamp = '2022-12-23T16:21:14.529Z' #timestamp string
format = ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]+'Z' #format pattern

to_datetime = datetime.strptime(timestamp,format) #convert to datetime
add1_hour = (to_datetime + timedelta(hours=1)) #add one hour
print(type(add1_hour),add1_hour)


#Convert datetime to string
to_string = str(add1_hour)
print(type(to_string),to_string)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\PYTHON_PROJECTS\tiny3.py", line 259, in <module>
    to_datetime = datetime.strptime(timestamp,format) #convert to datetime
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2022-12-23T16:21:14.529Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
```

Comment: Why are you chopping the last three characters off your format pattern?

Comment: Also, why are you shadowing the built-in *format()* function?

Comment: @tzaman Because microseconds comes with 6 digits, and I only need 3 + Z.

Comment: @Fred Sorry,I don't get the question. Shadowing?

Comment: The effect of `[:-3]` is to remove the last three characters of the _format_ string, i.e. you're losing the `.%f`.  Which is why it doesn't match, because you're using a format string that does not expect milliseconds, but your time string _does_ have milliseconds.

Comment: @JohnGordon What I thought would happen was that 000000 would become 000, and then I can add Z at the end (000Z). So how can I fix it?

Comment: Shadowing means that you have created a variable or function that has the same name as a standard python function.  The local variable `format` hides the built-in python function `format()`.  It doesn't appear to matter in this specific case, but it's generally not good practice.

Comment: That format string doesn't have `000000`, nor does it have `000`, so I'm confused as to what you were thinking...

Comment: @JohnGordon Oh, dang, I didnt notice it... true... well, I just changed the variable to format_

Comment: The original time string (timestamp = '2022-12-23T16:21:14.529Z) ends with .529Z. So I used the microseconds notation (which uses 6 digits). But since 6 digits won't cut it, I needed to slice the last three digits, hence [:-3] and then add Z. That was my idea.

Comment: It seems like you expected the `[:-3]` to apply to the time strings that are used as _input_ to the format string.  But no, that just chops off the last 3 characters of _the format string itself_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the built in methods for parsing and writing ISO formatted timestamps. You'll have to remove and reattach the `'Z'` manually since it's not supported:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def alter_timestamp(timestamp, delta):
    dt = datetime.fromisoformat(timestamp[:-1])
    return (dt + delta).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds') + 'Z'

timestamp = '2022-12-23T16:21:14.529Z'
hour_added = alter_timestamp(timestamp, timedelta(hours=1))
print(hour_added)
# '2022-12-23T17:21:14.529Z'
```

Comment: That's great, but I still prefer the version you deleted. It was a two-liner. I'm using that one. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If all your timestamps are UTC, I think you can include `Z` in the format string and it will parse correctly?

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Convert string to datetime
timestamp = '2022-12-23T16:21:14.529Z'  # timestamp string
to_datetime = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')  # convert to datetime

add1_hour = (to_datetime + timedelta(hours=1))  # add one hour
print(type(add1_hour), add1_hour)

# Convert datetime to string
to_string = str(add1_hour)
print(type(to_string), to_string)
```

Output:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'> 2022-12-23 17:21:14.529000
<class 'str'> 2022-12-23 17:21:14.529000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Terry. The only thing is that I need to replace those last 3 zeros with the letter Z. The timestamp is very finicky about it and won't accept anything else. After all this wrangling, I need to reformat that to a more readable format like (2022-12-23 / 17:21:14)

Comment: Use strftime() then to format the new timestamp without milliseconds-> `add1_hour.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Answer (score 1):

The [arrow module](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will make this much easier:

```py
import arrow

timestamp = '2022-12-23T16:21:14.529Z'
print(arrow.get(timestamp), arrow.get(timestamp).shift(hours=1))
```

Output:

```
2022-12-23T16:21:14.529000+00:00 2022-12-23T17:21:14.529000+00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know about arrow. Gonna look more into that!